# Filter Files and Order By Modify Date VB

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio, lambda

I'm filtering files by multiple extensions and i want to order by files date.

I'm trying
GetFiles().OrderByDescending(Function(p) p.LastWriteTime)

but cant order like this.

```
Dim driver As DriveInfo = DriveInfo.GetDrives().Where(Function(x) x.DriveType = DriveType.Removable).FirstOrDefault
        If driver IsNot Nothing AndAlso driver.IsReady Then
            UsbRootPath = Path.GetPathRoot(driver.RootDirectory.ToString)
            Dim ext = {".png", ".jpg", "*.zip"}
            Dim rootFiles() As String = ext.SelectMany(Function(f) Directory.GetFiles(driver.RootDirectory.ToString, f, SearchOption.TopDirectoryOnly)).ToArray()
End If
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I'm trying `GetFiles().OrderByDescending(Function(p) p.LastWriteTime)`

Well, that doesn't work because you use it in a `SelectMany`, so in kind of a sub-query. You need to apply the ordering last. Also, `p` is a `String`, the path, you need `File.GetLastWriteTime`:

```
Dim rootFiles() As String = ext.
    SelectMany(Function(f) Directory.EnumerateFiles(driver.RootDirectory.ToString, f, SearchOption.TopDirectoryOnly)).
    OrderByDescending(Function(f) File.GetLastWriteTime(f)).
    ToArray()
```

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest that you use the `DirectoryInfo` and `FileInfo` classes:

```
Dim fileInfos = extensions.SelectMany(Function(ext) New DirectoryInfo(driver.RootDirectory.FullName).
                           GetFiles("*" & ext)).
                           OrderBy(Function(fi) fi.LastWriteTime)
```

Exactly what you do from there depends on exactly what you want.  If you want the full path of each file in an array:

```
Dim filePaths = fileInfos.Select(Function(fi) fi.FullName).ToArray()
```